# Regex to parse malformed python dict

Tags: python, regex

I've a list of JSON such this:

```
{
    'title' : 'Lorem Ipsum',
    'title2' : '_(Lorem Ipsum)',
    'description' : 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  <br>' + Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
         <br>' +
        'It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages',
    'urls' : [
        "https://www.lipsum.com/",
        "http://lv.lipsum.com/",
        "http://nl.lipsum.com/",
        "http://ro.lipsum.com/"
    ]
},
```

I would like to have a valid JSON such this:

```json
    {
        "title" : "Lorem Ipsum",
        "title2" : "_(Lorem Ipsum)",
        "description" : "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  <br>' + Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
             <br>' +
            'It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages",
        "urls" : [
            "https://www.lipsum.com/",
            "http://lv.lipsum.com/",
            "http://nl.lipsum.com/",
            "http://ro.lipsum.com/"
        ]
    }
```

I am using this python regex but it doesn't match `"description"` and `"urls"` fields:

```py
# import re
regex = re.compile(r'\'([a-zA-Z]*)\' : \'(.*)\',', re.MULTILINE)
res = re.sub(regex, r'"\1": "\2",', d)
```

Comment: You have some badly quoted json and want to correct the quotes? I do not envy you; this does not look like a fun job :(

Comment: This isn't JSON. It's Python code (except for the line breaks in the strings).

Comment: Am I missing something? Why aren't you using the `json` module and `json.dumps()`?

Comment: Is that continuation line the only issue?  That whole struct looks valid Python code, you can certainly use `json.dumps` as @Vercingatorix recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a regular expression to "parse" this; a regex is the wrong tool for this job, as it doesn't understand the structure / syntax of the input.

I'd try to first ask the person who creates that garbage output to write valid json or even xml, anything you can parse with standard tools.

If that is not possible, you can butcher it with a regex, but it will be an ugly hack that is likely to silently break if your input data changes in the wrong ways. In particular, in this example, it will break if the description field contains a single quote followed by a comma, or if any field or name contains double quotes.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re
import json

garbage = """
{
    'title' : 'Lorem Ipsum',
    'title2' : '_(Lorem Ipsum)',
    'description' : 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  <br>' + Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
         <br>' +
        'It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was pop ularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages',
    'urls' : [
        "https://www.lipsum.com/",
        "http://lv.lipsum.com/",
        "http://nl.lipsum.com/",
        "http://ro.lipsum.com/"
    ]
},
"""

res = garbage
field_regex = re.compile(r"'([^']+)'\s*:\s*'(.+?)',", re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
res = re.sub(field_regex, r'"\1": "\2",', res)
list_regex = re.compile(r"'([^']+)'\s*:\s*\[", re.MULTILINE)
res = re.sub(list_regex, r'"\1": [', res)
res = re.sub("\n", " ", res, re.MULTILINE)
res = re.sub(",\s*$", "", res)

j = json.loads(res)
print(json.dumps(j, indent=4))
```

This butchers the garbage input and parses it as JSON, then prints it:

```json
{
    "title": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "title2": "_(Lorem Ipsum)",
    "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  <br>' + Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.          <br>' +         'It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages",
    "urls": [
        "https://www.lipsum.com/",
        "http://lv.lipsum.com/",
        "http://nl.lipsum.com/",
        "http://ro.lipsum.com/"
    ]
}
```

I changed these details compared to your original code:

- For readability: to define the regular expressions, use double quotes if the regex contains single ones, so that you don't have to escape single quotes.
- Replaced the match for the field names to look for a single quote instead of letters, in an attempt to make it more robust. Feel free to change this back.
- Replaced single spaces with `\s*` to capture zero to many spaces, again, in an attempt to be more robust and ignore white space changes.
- Added `re.DOTALL` to match over line breaks.
- Added another regex to match the list / array structure.
- Added another regex to replace newlines with spaces, as control characters like newlines are not valid in JSON fields. I'm assuming the newlines don't matter here. If they do, you'll need to replace them with quotes newlines.
- Removed a trailing comma at the end of the input. You could also tell the JSON parser to be lenient when parsing, which would allow trailing commas.

Again, this is a terrible hack. You should not use this in production. Fix the producer of this output.